# Scrape all urls from google-search-results, with lists of keywords?

Tags: search, keyword, google-search, keyword-search

I have a list of keywords, >300 keywords.
I would like to scrape all urls (+title) from google-search-results. I manually search word by word , and get list of keys by addon Linkclumb/Grabber

Is there any tool/software/ways help me to do it, for all 300 keywords, instead of each word.
Thanks so much

I have a list of keywords, >300 keywords.
I would like to scrape all urls (+title) from google-search-results. I manually search word by word , and get list of keys by addon Linkclumb/Grabber

Is there any tool/software/ways help me to do it, for all 300 keywords, instead of each word.
Thanks so much  .

Comment: Asking for external resources, including tools or libraries for a programming task, is off-topic here: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)